# Ruby - Separate out the first two digits from integer of increasing length

Tags: arrays, ruby, runtime-error

I keep getting the error below when running my code.

My Code:

```
class Integer
  def num_digits
    Math.log10(self).to_i + 1
  end

  def p(t)
    case t
    when 3
      return self * (self + 1) / 2
    when 4
      return self**2
    when 5
      return self * ((3 * self) - 1) / 2
    when 6
      return self * ((2 * self) - 1)
    when 7
      return self * ((5 * self) - 3) / 2
    when 8
      return self * ((3 * self) - 2)
    end
  end
end

$p3 = [], $p4 = [], $p5 = [], $p6 = [], $p7 = [], $p8 = []
$polygonals = [$p3, $p4, $p5, $p6, $p7, $p8]

(3..8).each_with_index do |t, index|
  i = 1
  until i == 150
    $polygonals[index] << i.p(t)
    i += 1
  end
end

$polygonals.each { |array| array.reject! { |x| x.num_digits != 4 } }
```

Error:

```
`block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `num_digits' for []:Array (NoMethodError)
```

However, if I change the last line of code to:

```
$polygonals.each { |array| array.each { |x| x.reject! { |y| y.num_digits != 4 } } }
```

I get the error:

```
`block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `reject!' for 1:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

How can `x` be type `array` in the first case and type `Fixnum` in the second?

Comment: This code contains multiple mistakes... It's also not "the ruby way" of writing it; I'm guessing ruby is not your first language?

Comment: Can you point out my mistakes? No it's not, I'm still learning idiomatic ruby.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? What is your expected output?

Comment: I have edited to include the rest of my code. I want to fill each array in `$polygonals` such that each number only has 4 digits.

Comment: Woah woah woah... Monkey patching the `Integer` class with a mysterious, 1-letter method that only works for inputs in the range `3..8`?! OK hang on, let me write up something for you... You've gone down a very strange path here.

Comment: Numbered variable names are a code smell. You should use a hash instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commas on this line

```
 $p3 = [], $p4 = [], $p5 = [], $p6 = [], $p7 = [], $p8 = []
```

Don't do what you think. In ruby

```
 a = 1,2
```

sets `a` to `[1,2]`, so this is setting `$p3` to

```
 [[], [], [], [], [], []]
```

If you put those assignments on separate lines or use `;` rather than commas then those variables will be initialised to what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** 
The reason for your failure is shown below:

```
irb(main):072:0> $polygonals = [$p3, $p4, $p5, $p6, $p7, $p8]
=> [[[], [], [], [], [], []], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Observe how does your first element look like. Not exactly as you would have expected, right?

Actually you have both. See how your $polygonals[0] look like:

> irb(main):066:0> $polygonals[0]=> [[], [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64,
>   81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484,
>   529, 576, 625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900, 961, 1024, 1089, 1156, 1225,
>   1296, 1369, 1444, 1521,1600, 1681, 1764, 1849, 1936, 2025, 2116, 2209,
>   2304, 2401, 2500, 2601, 2704, 2809, 2916, 3025, 3136, 3249, 3364,
>   3481, 3600, 3721, 3844, 3969, 4096, 4225, 4356, 4489, 4624, 4761,
>   4900, 5041, 5184, 5329, 5476, 5625, 5776, 5929, 6084, 6241, 6400,
>   6561, 6724, 6889, 7056, 7225, 7396, 7569, 7744, 7921,8100, 8281, 8464,
>   8649, 8836, 9025, 9216, 9409, 9604, 9801, 10000, 10201, 10404, 10609,
>   10816, 11025, 11236, 11449, 11664, 11881, 12100, 12321, 12544, 12769,
>   12996, 13225, 13456, 13689, 13924, 14161,14400, 14641, 14884, 15129,
>   15376, 15625, 15876, 16129, 16384, 16641, 16900, 17161, 17424, 17689,
>   17956, 18225, 18496, 18769, 19044, 19321, 19600, 19881, 20164, 20449,
>   20736, 21025, 21316, 21609, 21904, 22201], [1, 5, 12, 22, 35, 51, 70,
>   92, 117, 145, 176, 210, 247, 287, 330, 376, 425, 477, 532, 590, 651,
>   715, 782, 852, 925, 1001, 1080, 1162, 1247, 1335, 1426, 1520, 1617,
>   1717, 1820, 1926, 2035, 2147, 2262, 2380, 2501, 2625, 2752, 2882,
>   3015, 3151, 3290, 3432, 3577, 3725, 3876, 4030, 4187, 4347,4510, 4676,
>   4845, 5017, 5192, 5370, 5551, 5735, 5922, 6112, 6305, 6501, 6700,
>   6902, 7107, 7315, 7526, 7740, 7957, 8177, 8400, 8626, 8855, 9087,
>   9322, 9560, 9801, 10045, 10292, 10542, 10795, 11051, 11310, 11572,
>   11837, 12105, 12376, 12650, 12927, 13207, 13490, 13776, 14065, 14357,
>   14652, 14950, 15251, 15555, 15862, 16172, 16485, 16801, 17120, 17442,
>   17767, 18095, 18426, 18760, 19097, 19437, 19780,20126, 20475, 20827,
>   21182, 21540, 21901, 22265, 22632, 23002, 23375, 23751, 24130, 24512,
>   24897, 25285, 25676, 26070, 26467, 26867, 27270, 27676, 28085, 28497,
>   28912, 29330, 29751, 30175, 30602, 31032, 31465, 31901, 32340, 32782,
>   33227], [1, 6, 15, 28, 45, 66, 91, 120, 153, 190, 231, 276, 325, 378,
>   435, 496, 561, 630, 703, 780, 861, 946, 1035, 1128, 1225, 1326, 1431,
>   1540, 1653, 1770, 1891, 2016, 2145, 2278, 2415, 2556, 2701, 2850,
>   3003, 3160, 3321, 3486, 3655, 3828, 4005, 4186, 4371, 4560, 4753,
>   4950, 5151, 5356, 5565, 5778, 5995, 6216, 6441, 6670, 6903, 7140,
>   7381, 7626, 7875, 8128, 8385,8646, 8911, 9180, 9453, 9730, 10011,
>   10296, 10585, 10878, 11175, 11476, 11781, 12090, 12403, 12720,13041,
>   13366, 13695, 14028, 14365, 14706, 15051, 15400, 15753, 16110, 16471,
>   16836, 17205, 17578, 17955, 18336, 18721, 19110, 19503, 19900, 20301,
>   20706, 21115, 21528, 21945, 22366, 22791, 23220, 23653, 24090, 24531,
>   24976, 25425, 25878, 26335, 26796, 27261, 27730, 28203, 28680, 29161,
>   29646, 30135,30628, 31125, 31626, 32131, 32640, 33153, 33670, 34191,
>   34716, 35245, 35778, 36315, 36856, 37401, 37950, 38503, 39060, 39621,
>   40186, 40755, 41328, 41905, 42486, 43071, 43660, 44253], [1, 7, 18,
>   34, 55, 81, 112, 148, 189, 235, 286, 342, 403, 469, 540, 616, 697,
>   783, 874, 970, 1071, 1177, 1288, 1404,1525, 1651, 1782, 1918, 2059,
>   2205, 2356, 2512, 2673, 2839, 3010, 3186, 3367, 3553, 3744, 3940,
>   4141, 4347, 4558, 4774, 4995, 5221, 5452, 5688, 5929, 6175, 6426,
>   6682, 6943, 7209, 7480, 7756, 8037, 8323, 8614, 8910, 9211, 9517,
>   9828, 10144, 10465, 10791, 11122, 11458, 11799, 12145, 12496, 12852,
>   13213, 13579, 13950, 14326, 14707, 15093, 15484, 15880, 16281, 16687,
>   17098, 17514, 17935, 18361, 18792, 19228, 19669, 20115, 20566, 21022,
>   21483, 21949, 22420, 22896, 23377, 23863, 24354, 24850, 25351,25857,
>   26368, 26884, 27405, 27931, 28462, 28998, 29539, 30085, 30636, 31192,
>   31753, 32319, 32890, 33466, 34047, 34633, 35224, 35820, 36421, 37027,
>   37638, 38254, 38875, 39501, 40132, 40768, 41409, 42055, 42706, 43362,
>   44023, 44689, 45360, 46036, 46717, 47403, 48094, 48790, 49491, 50197,
>   50908, 51624, 52345, 53071, 53802, 54538, 55279], [1, 8, 21, 40, 65,
>   96, 133, 176, 225, 280, 341, 408, 481, 560,645, 736, 833, 936, 1045,
>   1160, 1281, 1408, 1541, 1680, 1825, 1976, 2133, 2296, 2465, 2640,
>   2821, 3008, 3201, 3400, 3605, 3816, 4033, 4256, 4485, 4720, 4961,
>   5208, 5461, 5720, 5985, 6256, 6533, 6816,7105, 7400, 7701, 8008, 8321,
>   8640, 8965, 9296, 9633, 9976, 10325, 10680, 11041, 11408, 11781,
>   12160, 12545, 12936, 13333, 13736, 14145, 14560, 14981, 15408, 15841,
>   16280, 16725, 17176, 17633, 18096,18565, 19040, 19521, 20008, 20501,
>   21000, 21505, 22016, 22533, 23056, 23585, 24120, 24661, 25208, 25761,
>   26320, 26885, 27456, 28033, 28616, 29205, 29800, 30401, 31008, 31621,
>   32240, 32865, 33496, 34133, 34776, 35425, 36080, 36741, 37408, 38081,
>   38760, 39445, 40136, 40833, 41536, 42245, 42960, 43681, 44408, 45141,
>   45880, 46625, 47376, 48133, 48896, 49665, 50440, 51221, 52008, 52801,
>   53600, 54405,55216, 56033, 56856, 57685, 58520, 59361, 60208, 61061,
>   61920, 62785, 63656, 64533, 65416, 66305], 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28,
>   36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91, 105, 120, 136, 153, 171, 190, 210, 231, 253,
>   276, 300, 325, 351, 378, 406, 435, 465, 496, 528, 561, 595, 630, 666,
>   703, 741, 780, 820, 861, 903, 946, 990, 1035, 1081, 1128, 1176, 1225,
>   1275, 1326, 1378, 1431, 1485, 1540, 1596, 1653, 1711, 1770, 1830,
>   1891, 1953, 2016, 2080, 2145, 2211, 2278, 2346, 2415, 2485, 2556,
>   2628, 2701, 2775, 2850, 2926, 3003,3081, 3160, 3240, 3321, 3403, 3486,
>   3570, 3655, 3741, 3828, 3916, 4005, 4095, 4186, 4278, 4371, 4465,
>   4560, 4656, 4753, 4851, 4950, 5050, 5151, 5253, 5356, 5460, 5565,
>   5671, 5778, 5886, 5995, 6105, 6216, 6328, 6441, 6555, 6670, 6786,
>   6903, 7021, 7140, 7260, 7381, 7503, 7626, 7750, 7875, 8001, 8128,8256,
>   8385, 8515, 8646, 8778, 8911, 9045, 9180, 9316, 9453, 9591, 9730,
>   9870, 10011, 10153, 10296,10440, 10585, 10731, 10878, 11026, 11175]

And this is how your $polygonals[1] look like:

> irb(main):067:0> $polygonals[1]=> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81,
>   100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529,
>   576, 625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900, 961, 1024, 1089, 1156, 1225, 1296,
>   1369, 1444, 1521, 1600, 1681, 1764, 1849, 1936, 2025, 2116, 2209,
>   2304, 2401, 2500, 2601, 2704, 2809, 2916, 3025, 3136, 3249, 3364,
>   3481, 3600, 3721, 3844, 3969, 4096, 4225, 4356, 4489, 4624, 4761,
>   4900, 5041, 5184, 5329, 5476, 5625, 5776, 5929, 6084, 6241, 6400,
>   6561, 6724, 6889, 7056, 7225, 7396, 7569, 7744, 7921, 8100, 8281,
>   8464, 8649, 8836, 9025, 9216, 9409, 9604, 9801, 10000, 10201, 10404,
>   10609, 10816, 11025, 11236, 11449, 11664, 11881, 12100, 12321, 12544,
>   12769, 12996, 13225, 13456, 13689, 13924, 14161, 14400, 14641, 14884,
>   15129, 15376, 15625, 15876, 16129, 16384, 16641, 16900, 17161, 17424,
>   17689, 17956,18225, 18496, 18769, 19044, 19321, 19600, 19881, 20164,
>   20449, 20736, 21025, 21316, 21609, 21904, 22201]

Answer (score 0):

First off, it's generally considered bad practice to extend core classes such as `Integer`. You should only do this in special circumstances, where you are providing generic, useful behaviour that your application can use throughout.

The two methods you have written are both bad examples of when to do this:

```
class Integer
  def num_digits
    Math.log10(self).to_i + 1
  end
end
```

Why bother with such a mathematical technique (`123.num_digits == 3`) when you could just do something like: `123.to_s.length == 3`?

```
  def p(t)
    case t
    when 3
      return self * (self + 1) / 2
    # ...
    when 8
      return self * ((3 * self) - 2)
    end
  end
end
```

What the heck is this?! What does `p` mean, why does the method only work for integers `3..8` (otherwise it returns `nil`)? I'm guessing it's to do with calculating polygonal numbers, in which case you should name it as such. This has no place in the `Integer` class; just make it a separate method, and name it better:

```
def rename_me(x, y) # What are x and y? What IS this method? Use real words!
  case y
  when 3
    x * (x + 1) / 2
  # ...
  when 8
    x * ((3 * x) - 2)
  end
end
```

Next, never use global variables, unless you have a very good reason to. In ruby, variable names starting with `$` are global. Instead of `$polygonals`, just define variables like `polygonals`.

Next, learn how to define variables in ruby. Writing code like `x = 1, y = 2` is not doing what you think; that's actually setting `x == [1, 2]` and `y == 2`. The intention here is that a possible shorthand for defining variables is: `x, y = 1, 2` which sets `x == 1` and `y == 2` - but I wouldn't generally recommend 1-line definitions like this; just put it on 2 lines.

With all of this in mind, here is how I would write your full code in a more "ruby way":

---

```
def rename_me(x, y) # What are x and y? What IS this method? Use real words!
  case y
  when 3
    x * (x + 1) / 2
  # ...
  when 8
    x * ((3 * x) - 2)
  end
end

polygonals = ([(1..149)] * 6)
  .map.with_index do |range, index|
    range
      .map { |x| rename_me(x, index + 3) }
      .select { |x| x.to_s.length == 4 }
  end
```

However (!!) you should use better variables names than I have above. Don't just call things `x` etc, unless they are just scratch variables; e.g. using `i` as an index can be OK sometimes.

Comment: w.r.t extending the core classes, I'm aware it's bad practice; a lot of what you see is self practicing so that I'm familiar with all the different options available to me. Duly noted about better descriptions for functions and variables though and thanks for outlining what the actual problem was with my code.